# First new line in multi-line vim commands has broken highlighting

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting

In my init.vim I have the following command:

```
nnoremap <Leader>s :echo "hi<" . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name")
  \ . "> fg<" . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"fg")
  \ . "> bg<" . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"bg") . ">"<CR>
```

For some reason though, the syntax shows up like this:

[image]

As you can see, the second line has no highlighting whatsoever. This happens every time I try to do something like this, and I don't know why. If I write the following:

```
nnoremap <Leader>s 
  \ :echo "hi<" . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name")  
  \ . "> fg<" . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"fg")
  \ . "> bg<" . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"bg") . ">"<CR>
```

It shows up like this:

[image]

Which is mostly correct, but if you look closely, the `.` in the first line has no highlighting, so it is still broken. How can I fix this?

More info:

- I'm using Neovim 0.4.4-1.
- This is all the text on my init.vim, the rest has been commented out.
- Probably doesn't matter, but my terminal is kitty 0.18.3-1.
- I've checked to see if there was any whitespace at the end of the lines, there is none.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I wonder if it's a configuration problem; see [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I fix this?

Stop bullying the syntax highlighter ;-)

> `:h g:vimsyn_noerror` **Vim script is a difficult language to highlight correctly.**

Put your code into a dedicated function instead.